# Visual Studio Xamarin Intellisense Not Working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense, codelens

While using Visual Studio 2015 with the latest updates, Intellisense and CodeLens do not work properly. Syntax highlighting, code completion, and property/method references (not sure the exact name for this) are shown very inconsistently, or not at all. These work for some things, and don't for most others. Errors do not show up at all without an explicit build, and even then, they show up one at a time, which is very time-consuming.

I should note that this is not happening in XAML, just my .cs files. I was not able to reproduce these issues in either a WPF project or a Windows Forms project; I'm only seeing this in my Xamarin.Forms solution.

I've tried restarting VS, closing the solution and restarting VS, restarting my machine, resetting the "Statement Completion" settings in VS options, deleting the solution's .suo file, resetting settings via the Import and Export Settings Wizard, but nothing has changed. I would appreciate any suggestions.

**Update**: Uninstalling all Xamarin-related VS extensions and NuGet packages, then reinstalling seems to have fixed things, at least for now.

**Further update**: I ended up seeing this problem again not long after my first update. It turns out the path for one of my projects had too many characters (???), so I moved the whole solution folder to the root of my C drive. I haven't had any problems since.

Comment: Hi, This is odd. I am a Xamarin support engineer and I have only ever seen/heard of intellisense errors with Forms XAML. I might first suggest that you make sure you are on all of the latest stable versions of the  Xamarin tools (Xamarin for VS) and Xamarin Forms packages. Some more description of the project(s) that intellisense is or is not working in might be helpful, i.e. is it in the Forms PCL or Shared core project, or the Android and/or iOS platform specific projects?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is with a shared core project, and I'm seeing it in all of the projects in this solution, including the shared code, Android, and iOS projects. Once I'm back at the office, I'll make sure that everything Xamarin-related is up to date. If that doesn't solve things, my next step may be to completely reinstall VS.

Answer (score 1):

For those, having xaml intellisense problem and you are using Resharper;

> Disable ReSharper!

Visual Studio > Tools | Options | ReSharper | General : Suspend

**Update:**
*When I install the latest ReSharper version (2017.2), the problem is solved.*